# Chef and PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, amazon-rds

With amazon annoucing postgresql service in RDS, can we setup chef-server(11) with amazon rds postgresql database, rather than using the default databse that gets installed with the omnibus installer. I have read that we can achieve same by configuring chef-server.rb file and then reconfiguring the chef-server, but can't get what setttings to specify in the chef-server.rb file. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I did not try this, but it seems rather straightforward.

Check your `chef-server-running.json`, it should be in `/etc/chef-server`. The file has properties listed with which chef-server is running. Scroll down to "postgresql" - you will see some properties used for connecting to postgresql database.

Add the properties you would like to change (such as *listen_address* or *sql_password*) into `chef-server.rb` file like that:

```
postgresql['listen_address'] = 'new_host'
postgresql['sql_password'] = 'new_password'
```

and run

```
chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

Then start chef-server and make sure that `chef-server-running.json` now has new values for postgresql.

Hopefully that helps.